# Не получается получить доступ к вайфай на телефоне с помощью приложения

Tags: java, android

Я пишу простое приложение что то вроде чата, которое будет работать без интернета с помощью Wifi direct | Проблема в том что при нажатии на кнопу On и Off ничего не происходит вайфай не включается и не выключается не могу найти ошибку разрешение в манифесте добавила

```
   package biybinaz.uz.localconnect2;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button btnOnOff, btnDiscover, btnSend;
        ListView listView;
        TextView read_msg_box, connectionStatus;
        EditText writeMsg;
        WifiManager wifiManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        intialWork();
        exqListener();
    }

    private void intialWork() {
        btnOnOff = findViewById(R.id.onOff);
        btnDiscover = findViewById(R.id.discover);
        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.peerListView);
        read_msg_box = findViewById(R.id.readMsg);
        connectionStatus = findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);
        writeMsg = findViewById(R.id.writeMsg);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    }
    private void exqListener() {
        btnOnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    btnOnOff.setText("Wifi On");
                } else {
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    btnOnOff.setText("Wifi Off");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/onOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:text="Wifi On" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/discover"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/onOff"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/onOff"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="discover" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/peerListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/onOff"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/readMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/peerListView"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="Message"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/writeMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sendButton"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_message"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Send" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connectionStatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Connection Status"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</RelativeLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LocalConnect2"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```